# What unroots the trees?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-road

In the movie "The Road" (2009) there is a scene where the protagonists need to stop running and seek shelter (laying on the ground between the trunks of two fallen trees), as the trees around them become unrooted and fall to the ground. It is as if something invisible is moving through the air and forcing them to the ground.

The fact that the trees do no break suggests that they are not already old and rotten. In a way, this scene reminds of the the events in the series "Lost" (2004-2010), where trees get destroyed on the island.

**Is there some explanation for the trees being unrooted in the movie "The Road"?** Is there any "link" between the trees falling in the two movies? (e.g., just using a similar idea, paying tribute, ..)

**Clarification**: I do not ask about what caused the disaster (war, epidemic, meteorite, ..). I also do not ask about the trees which have already fallen (e.g., the trees which cover the surface of the river). I ask about the trees which were upright, and fall *exactly* when the protagonists are there (they were running away from some bad people).

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/887/what-is-the-extinction-event

Comment: Haven’t seen it but trees eventually fall and it’s not unusual in a story for there too be just bad luck that events like trees falling over happen right as some character is nearby.

Comment: @ Everybody until now: I do NOT ask about the cataclysm. I ask about something that happened in the middle of the movie. You can understand only if you see the movie.

Comment: Will someone please be kind and explain how I can improve my question? And to explain the downvotes?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there some explanation for the trees falling in "The Road"?

#### It was an earthquake.

Watching the following scene a couple times, it's not *entirely* obvious that that's what was happening since the sound & visual effects could have been from the trees themselves uprooting and falling. So, IMO the OP is a valid question.

The book also has an earthquake occur but no explanation was provided regarding a correlation between the earthquake(s) and the cataclysmic event.

> It neared, growing louder. Everything trembling. Then it passed beneath them like an underground train and drew away into the night and was gone. The boy clung to him crying, his head buried against his chest. Shh. It's all right.
> I'm so scared.
> I know. It's all right. It's gone.
> What was it, Papa?
> It was an earthquake. It's gone now. We're all right. Shh.

There's also a [Sci-fi & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8/what-was-the-catastrophe-that-happened-in-the-road) post that talks around the earthquake(s) and what may or may not be causing them (and other portrayed-to-be after effects of the extinction event).

Comment: That could be true. When I will remember, I will re-watch that part. Now I am even more curious, to "analyze".